# Typescript: union of functions

Tags: typescript

There are two function types, one returns `string` and other one returns a `Promise<string>`. Now I'd like to have a function to wrap them, but I have to distinguish each one while invoking `fn`

```
type FuncTypes = (...args: any[]) => string | Promise<string>

function callFunc(fn: FuncTypes, ...args: any[]) {
  // distinguish fn returns string or Promise<string>
  // if fn returns string
    return new Promise<string>(r => r(fn.call(this, ...args)))
  // if fn returns a Promise
    return fn.call(this, ...args)
}
```

Another situation is overload:

```
type FuncA = (...args: any[]) => string
type FuncB = (...args: any[]) => Promise<string>

function callFunc(fn: FuncA, ...args: any[]): Promise<string>
function callFunc(fn: FuncB, ...args: any[]): Promise<string>
function callFunc(fn: any, ...args: any[]): Promise<string> {
  // if fn is instanceof FuncA
  // do sth.
  // else if fn is instanceof FuncB
  // do sth
}
```

Although we can simply use `const returned = fn(..args); typeof returned === 'string'` to check returned type, it is not a general solution. If function type is `() => AnInterface|AnotherInterface`, it's difficult to check return type by using `typeof` or `instanceof`.

Is there any general way to distinguish them? or should I write two functions for  each type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In that specific case

> There are two function types, one returns string and other one returns a Promise. Now I'd like to have a function to wrap them, but I have to distinguish each one while invoking fn

In that **specific** case, `callFunc` can just be this:

```
function callFunc(fn: FuncTypes, ...args: any[]) {
    return <Promise<string>>Promise.resolve(fn.call(this, ...args));
}
```

If `fn` returns a promise, the promise from `Promise.resolve` will be resolved to the promise returned by `fn` (it will wait for that promise to settle and settle the same way); if it doesn't, you'll have a fulfilled promise with the return value of `fn` as its resolution value.

### In the general case

> Is there any general way to distinguish them?

Not at runtime, unless you annotate them in some way (more in a moment). TypeScript's type information is compile-time only.

> or should I write two functions for each type?

That's probably best.

You could annotate the functions, for instance by putting a property on them indicating what their return type is:

```
function delay(ms: number, value: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));
}
(<any>delay).returnValue = "Promise<string>";
```

At that point, you're duplicating the type information (once for TypeScript, again for your own code).

So your solution of writing two functions is probably best.